# Sphinx + HTML Help Workshop : separate page for each section

Tags: html, python-sphinx, chm, html-help-workshop

After building *.rst files with Sphinx, I am creating a CHM file with the HTML Help Workshop.

My index.rst file so far:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   _static/presentation_designer/feedback
   _static/presentation_designer/test
```

I have two *.rst files which are under the 'presentation_designer' folder. Each feedback.rst and test.rst file has its own separate page in the CHM file.

**feedback.rst**

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
**Presentation Designer**
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
**Leave Feedback**
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Please feel free to leave feedback.
```

**test.rst**

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
**Presentation Designer**
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
**test**
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Please test and click ‘submit’.
```

---

But I've got the result as shown in the attached file.

How can I put them (Test and Feedback pages) under "Presentation Designer" together?

[image: section issue]

Comment: How did you get the topics in order of single level below a folder one can see above the marked "Presentation Designer"?

Comment: I think you're asking about the folder which includes "Upload scenes" and "Schedule presentations". Right?

That folder came from a separate single file which contains different sub-sections (e.g. "Upload scenes" and "Schedule presentations"). For simplicity, I didn't include them in index.rst above, but forget to remove them in the picture. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, I saw the perfect structure on top you are asking for here for the two topics below in your snapshot. Do you want all this in "single sourcing" means one index.rst? Or do you want to add two special HTML topics as a result of a second index rst and compile together as one CHM by hand using HTML Help Workshop? I'm asking because it's possible to edit the e.g. foobar.hhp for few topics by hand before compiling.

Comment: @help-info.de I haven't thought about a second index rst file. I think it would be better to have a single index.rst file if possible.

Basically, my question is kind of simple. "How can I put two sections (in this example,  separate rst files - feedback.rst and test.rst) under a single  section (in this example, the marked "Presentation Designer")?"  Are you clear about that? 

If it is not possible to do that with a single index.rst, it would be fine to have a second index.rst. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, the Table of Contents (TOC) in a CHM's navigation pane is derived from your restructured text file and normally depending on the title, subtitle und subsubtitle.

Please have a look at the following screenshot (navigation pane) for your special requirements and the source files below. The resulting CHM I compiled using [FAR HTML](https://www.help-info.de/far-html.html) but using Microsoft's HTML Help Workshop is working for this too.

[image: Help Viewer with navigation pane and content.]

**index.rst:**

```
Welcome - CHM Sphinx Demo
=========================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   first-steps/overview
   _static/presentation-designer/_presentation-designer
```

**overview.rst:**

```
********
Overview
********

About FAR HTML
##############
... some text

Features
########
... some text

Help Authoring:
***************
... some text
```

**_presentation-designer.rst:**

```
Presentation Designer
=====================

.. toctree::

   coaching
   feedback
```

**coaching.rst:**

.. toctree::
:maxdepth: 1

```
Coaching conversations
######################

Feedback should not be a one-way street.
```

**feedback.rst:**

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

Real-time Feedback
##################

Feedback happens less than it should and often comes too late.
```